# Get IP from e-mail

Tags: email

Good morning,
This is the first time I use this forum, once all the other answers I could find on google, however, I couldn't find this one.

I am using Openpop.net in VB.NET to develop a service to send and capture e-mails and I need to put, among other informations, the Origin and destination IPs from the e-mail, but I can't find it how to do it.

Could Someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the IP with a .NET API specific for that.

Answer (score 0):

the IP may be (if it is) in MIME headers. 
Look for  X-Originating-IP or Received header.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have looked for that already and found nothing.

Comment: the IP is not always set in email.

Comment: I was able to get the sender IP (from received property, in headers), however, I believe it's not possible to retrieve the destination IP.